# what the following syntax means in perl?

Tags: perl

```
my $dir = $ENV{"CDSSITE_INI_DIR"};
```

hello, I'm new to Perl. I'm confused with the curly braces above syntax.
I know it is declared a scalar variable $dir. But what do the curly braces mean in that statement?

Comment: You need a better perl book. Hashes are one of the fundamental perl data structures.

Comment: It is an instruction to assign variable `$dir` value of environment $CDSSITE_INI_DIR. You can check content environment  variable with shell command `echo $CDSSITE_INI_DIR`.

Answer (score 3):

Perl populates a global hash (`%ENV`) with the environment variables. To get any value, you must use the `$ENV{'env-var-name'}` syntax. That is the way to access a concrete value in a hash, using curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

It's retrieving the value from a hash based on key 'CDSITE_INI_DIR'. But in this case it's a special hash from the OS variables.
You can code your own hash such as this:

```
my %depts;
my $south = 'SOUTH';
$depts{'EAST'} = 123;
$depts{WEST} = 456;
$depts{$south} = 789;
print $depts{WEST} . "\n";
```

Note: different ways I set the keys.
Perl automatically creates a hash called %ENV and puts the environment variables with their values into that hash at startup. Such as $HOME, etc.
Hashes (key/value pairs) and arrays serve different purposes. Both are very useful depending on need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I now understand. Perl script automatically has a hash %ENV and it get the value out of hash with key "CDSSITE_INI_DIR" and assigns it to a scalar variable $dir.